# How do I add user defined folders as application classpath in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I am working on Ant to Gradle migration for a java application  It's built using Spring MVC.
I have an XML file containing the beans the application needs. It's located under `src/main/resources/spring`.

If I put the file under `src/main/resources` it's working perfectly. But I need to put it in the `spring` folder.

When I'm putting the file inside this folder it shows:
`Class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Do I need to write some gradle tasks to make gradle look into the specific folder??

Comment: try adding the following in build.gradle: sourceSets { main { resources { srcDir 'src/main/resources/spring' } } } and see if that helps (indent the above code acc.)

Comment: Is it really the matter of gradle? Rather of telling spring where to look for this file.

Comment: The sourceset example worked.but in the build folder all the configs are getting generated all together but that I can live with.thanks for the help

Comment: I can't tell where to look coz I have to use their API . I can't customize that